# Spring boot custom Basic authentication

Tags: java, spring-boot

**I have excluded basic authentication with the following:**

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = [SecurityAutoConfiguration::class])
class Application {

    @Bean
    fun rpcClient(): WrapperRpcClient {
        val client = WrapperRpcClient()
        client.createClient()
        return client
    }
}
```

**and added the custom security but it's not working**

```
@Configuration

@EnableWebSecurity

    public class BasicConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
                 auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user")
                .password("password")
                .roles("USER")
                .and()
                .withUser("admin")
                .password("admin")
                .roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                //HTTP Basic authentication
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/books/**").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/books").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/books/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PATCH, "/books/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/books/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .formLogin().disable();
    }
}
```

**Please help.**

Comment: What is not working? please share more details with stacktrace

Comment: I have created a custom securityconfig by extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. But it still generating auto password. 

Using generated security password: d4695c01-a88e-458e-978d-cf121726ea50

If I am same  doing on separate project it works fine but spring boot client with corda blockchain is not working.

Comment: the issue was having java file once i converted it to kotlin started working.

Answer (score 1):

Try configuring MethodSecurity

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
    prePostEnabled = true,
    securedEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfigurer extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

}
```

check [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-method-security)

Comment: I have created the separate application with same code base and auth working. But when using with corda blockchain it's not working very strange.